# Полная пересборка проекта

Tags: android, android-ndk

Есть проект на Android NDK. Как перекомплировать и перелинковать все файлы проекта, не только недавно измененные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно при вызове `ndk-build` передать опцию `-B`, тогда будет выполнена полная сборка.

```
$ ndk-build -B
```